# Rename Bucket or transfer all models

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to know if it is possible to rename a Bucket.
If not, I would like to know if I can move all my models on the bucket I want to rename to a new bucket without translating each model again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to rename a bucket, but it is possible to copy files (objects) across bucket with this [API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-copyto-:newObjectName-PUT/)

For the viewables, it is a different story - they are not stored in OSS buckets, but on the Model Derivatives server. It means, you either need to translate them again if you want to use the new URN, or leave them where they are and map the old and new URNs. Viewables are destroyed only when you delete their manifest.